# Trace map of user movement in background and show all the trace after the user clicks button

Tags: android

I am developing an application which has a music player. Now I want to add map into that so that to trace map of the movement of user during the playlist is going on and after completion of the playlist there will be a button after clicking on the button the trace map is shown to the user and with that the distance traveled is also given to the user on basis of movement.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this... It will work
googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(lat1, lon1), new LatLng(lat2, lon2))
.width(5)
.color(Color.RED));